# Java generic type inheritance, List element type inference

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, type-inference

I have the following single-level inheritance. One thing that I can't wrap my head around is the fact that, `getLine()` is inferred as `BaseLine` without cast because of `BaseDocument<T extends BaseLine>`. But for list this doesn't apply, each element is returned as `Object`. My questions are:

1. Why compiler can't infer the element type as `BaseLine`.
2. How to change the implementation so I can get elements as `BaseLine` while iterating.

   ```
    public void test(){
        BaseDocument baseDocument = new Document();
        for (Object orderLine : baseDocument.getOrderLines()) {

        }

        BaseLine line = baseDocument.getLine();
    }


    static class Document extends BaseDocument<Line> {
        @Override
        public List<Line> getOrderLines() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Line getLine() {
            return null;
        }
    }

    static abstract class BaseDocument<T extends BaseLine> {
        public abstract List<T> getOrderLines();
        public abstract T getLine();
    }


    static class Line extends BaseLine {
    }

    static abstract class BaseLine {
    }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have:

```java
BaseDocument baseDocument = new Document();
```

You're using a *raw type*. A raw type erases all the generic information from the class. That includes other generic types. So with the above it's as if the class was written like so:

```java
static abstract class BaseDocument {

  public abstract List getOrderLines();

  public abstract BaseLine getLine();
}
```

The type parameter of `List` is implicitly bounded by `Object` and so erases to `Object`.

You should never use raw types unless you're forced to by legacy code (written before Java 5). If you don't want to give an actual type then use a wildcard:

```java
BaseDocument<?> baseDocument = new Document();
for (BaseLine orderLine : baseDocument.getOrderLines()) {
  // do something...
}
```

And you can leave the implementation of `BaseDocument` as is.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** This answer is more on the unsafe side, in my opinion. Check the answer from @Slaw for a better explanation. It has flaws too as explained by the author. Beware of complications when choosing between answers

The reason is in this specific line `BaseDocument baseDocument = new Document();`
`BaseDocumet<T extends BaseLine>` is the generic type and requires its type declared otherwise it can't infer the type of `T` so it automatically resolves to `Object`.

One way to resolve the problem is to cast `baseDocument.getOrderLines()` to `List<BaseLine>` as:

`List<BaseLine> lines = baseDocument.getOrderLines();` this will raise `uncheked cast` warning but project will compile

Comment: This just occurred to me (sorry for the wrong information): Actually, the issue I said regarding your solution where the wrong type could be added to the list? That's still possible when using the wildcard approach in my answer. Two ways I can think to prevent this is to return `List<? extends T>`  or to simply return an unmodifiable list (to prevent modification from the outside). In any case, it is definitely better to use the wildcard instead of the raw type.

Comment: Honestly, I was aware of "a wrong type could still be added when using wildcard". But I can't think of any better approach for my case. My concrete class `Document` requires to return a concrete implementation of `BaseLine`. I can't make my list immutable because other places should be able to modify that list given some conditions so this is not an option for me either.

Comment: Oh my god... I'm sorry about this. I checked with my IDE when the thought occurred to me, before posting my previous comment, and it gave no errors. It must have been updating or indexing or something, because now it does give an error. Doing `baseDocument.getOrderLines().add(new SomeOtherLine())` gives an `incompatible types: SomeOtherLine cannot be converted to CAP#1` error. Of course, there are still ways to "defeat" compile-time generic type checking but perhaps my solution doesn't have as bad a vulnerability as I thought.

Comment: Well, thanks to you. I just recalled that, you can't add something to a list defined as `List<? extends T>` because the list can be of any type that extends `T`. I made a mistake here too "I was aware of "a wrong type could still be added when using wildcard".". Thanks for pondering on it, really appreciate what you're doing